# CSS, retain element positioning during page zoom

Tags: css

I'm having trouble retaining the positioning of elements when opening the web page from different machines with different zoom settings.

so far, all elements including the body have a position of absolute (with relating position values).
I wish for all elements to hold their position during a zoom.

```
body{
   position: absolute;
   margin: 0;
   top: 0px;
   bottom: 0px;
   left: 0px;
   right: 0px;
}

#div1{
   position: absolute;
   top: 10%;
}

#div2{
   position: absolute;
   top: 10%
   left: 10%;
}
```

This is a abstracted example of my css, but that's pretty much the basis of it.
I've been sucsessful before with css to achieve 'dynamic' positioning during browser scrolling, but cannot remember what I used or did!

Comment: " all elements including the body have a position of absolute ". This is the source of your issues and is a poor layout method. [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: I agree to Paulie_D, please share your HTML and maybe an image of what you are trying to achieve. Then we can help you better.